# Sculpt tools not working

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I have just opened a new file from scratch, made a sphere and gone into sculpt mode, but none of the tools work except for the yellow ones like grab.

activating dynatopo doesn't change the issue

I dont think that there is any reason to post screenshots? as it is a brand new file with no changes made

Comment: also doesn't work if i make a new object

Comment: When in dyntopo, the blue tools do add faces, but do not make any physical change to the shape of the mesh

Comment: The sculpt mode only works along vertices.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to go to the 'tool' side panel and uncheck "strength pressure". This same problem was bugging me for over a day until I realized that setting was on, somehow. If it's checked and there's no tablet plugged in to provide pressure sensitivity options, the pressure will be set to 0 constantly and thus any brushes that are affected by pressure sensitivity (aka all non-yellow brushes) have no effect. Hope this answer helps anybody who stumbles across this problem in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's a glitch in the new 2.9 edition.  It's frustrating the hell out of me too.  It was working fine last night.  I read someone suggesting to simply revert backwards to 2.8.  But come on, Blender!  You're 3D modeling software.  Surely you should be able to pull off the FIRST THING ABOUT SCULPTING!  It's not like you haven't had to time to figure it out by version 2.9!  I'm so sick of the broken ass program.  You sure do get what you pay for.  Free as dirt!